# Getting content of body::after but empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to determine if my website is displayed with a certain resolution. To do it :

```
body::after {
  display: none;
  content: "desktop";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  body::after {
    content: "mobile"
  }
}
```

On the JavaScript Side:

```
(function() () {
    var devicetype = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body'), '::after').getPropertyValue('content');
    console.log(deviceType);
});
```

The output displays that deviceType is empty.

The thing is when I set a timeout of 2 seconds for example, the output displays the expected value!

What can I do ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure to understand the question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, why you do it that way?

Comment: Why aren't you using [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)?

Comment: Cause I decided to do it by the way of css.

Comment: @maurycy I am using it to determine if I have to run a certain function. If it's "mobile", I don't run this certain function

Comment: @Ricky, this is if I don't have the choice, that I will take the javascript way

Comment: Did you notice that you already use javascript? and @Ricky solutions is actually both easy and practical?

Comment: Yes, this is contrary. Okay, I'll use JavaScript. But I just want to set this thing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several syntax errors in your javascript code, correct them and it will work.

```js
(function() {
  var deviceType = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body'), '::after').content;
  console.log(deviceType);
})();
```

```css
body::after {
  display: none;
  content: "desktop";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  body::after {
    content: "mobile";
  }
}
```

---

There is no need to use CSS when Javascript is already being used and [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) is available.

```js
(function() {
  let deviceType = window.innerWidth > 736 ? "desktop" : "mobile";
  console.log(deviceType);
})();
```

Comment: I have no syntax error announced in my console... or I don't know what you mean by syntax error.